# VideoCapture works properly, but I always get ret = False for the first few frames

Tags: opencv

I'm able to read and display the video loaded from a file just fine. However, after displaying about first 10-12 frames, `retval = False` for some time and then the video proceeds flawlessly for rest of the time.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEOFILENAME.mp4)
while True:
    retval, image = cap.read()
    if retval:
        cv2.imshow("Video", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

I tried this with several different videos from several different sources. Could someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Could be that it has some faulty frames? It may return false when it is not able read the frames and decode them correctly

Comment: some decoders need multiple frames to create an image or special frames to create the first image. Maybe this is part of the problem.